# How do we ensure that the calls in the Mock.call_args_list contain calls with arguments at the same state of when the Mock object was called?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

```
from mock import Mock
j = []
u = Mock()
u(j)
# At this point u.call_args_list == [call([])]
print u.call_args_list
j.append(100)
# At this point u.call_args_list == [call([100])], but I expect it to be [call([])], since it was never called when j had a value of 100 in it
print u.call_args_list
```

My question is how do I ensure that the calls in `u.call_args_list` contain the states of all objects at the time of calling the mock rather than at the time of checking the arguments of the mock?

I am using `mock==1.0.1` at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is discussed in the documentation section [26.6.3.7. Coping with mutable arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#coping-with-mutable-arguments).

Unfortunately, they don't really have any elegant solution to the issue!  The recommended workaround is copying elements from the mutable arguments by using `side_effect`.

> If you provide a side_effect function for a mock then side_effect will be called with the same args as the mock. This gives us an opportunity to copy the arguments and store them for later assertions.

It's somewhat messy to implement, in my opinion.  If you need the capability in multiple places, you may prefer to subclass `Mock` and add the feature directly:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class CopyingMock(MagicMock):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        args = deepcopy(args)
        kwargs = deepcopy(kwargs)
        return super(CopyingMock, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

**2017**: It's now available in a third-party distribution (`pip install copyingmock`).

```
>>> from copyingmock import CopyingMock
>>> mock = CopyingMock()
>>> list_ = [1,2]
>>> mock(list_)
<CopyingMock name='mock()' id='4366094008'>
>>> list_.append(3)
>>> mock.assert_called_once_with([1,2])
>>> mock.assert_called_once_with(list_)

AssertionError: Expected call: mock([1, 2, 3])
Actual call: mock([1, 2])
```