# When exactly patched class methods are called?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock

While writing some tests today I came across a confusing behaviour:

`Foo` class definition:

```
class Foo:

    def bar(self, attrs):
        self._baz(attrs)
        attrs.pop('key')

    def _baz(self, attrs):
        pass
```

`Foo` class tests:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock


class FooTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_bar(self):
        foo = Foo()
        attrs = {'key': 'value'}
        with mock.patch.object(foo, '_baz') as _baz_mock:
            # Copying `attrs` so that `foo.bar()` won't mutate it.
            foo.bar({**attrs})
        # Test fails here since `_baz_mock` gets called with `{}` (not sure why).
        _baz_mock.assert_called_once_with(attrs)
```

I expected `_baz_mock.assert_called_once_with(attrs)` to pass successfully since `Foo.bar()` performs `attrs.pop('key')` *after* calling `self._baz(attrs)`, however [it fails](https://repl.it/repls/CircularAuthorizedInteger) with the following `AssertionError`:

```
Expected call: _baz({'key': 'value'})
Actual call: _baz({})
```

Could someone please explain what is going on here and why `_baz_mock` gets called with `{}`?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you'll find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248075/how-do-we-ensure-that-the-calls-in-the-mock-call-args-list-contain-calls-with-ar. The fact that the pop takes place after the call does not matter. The same mutable object is mutated.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Ah, I see. That makes sense though it's tricky. Thanks!